# homemade antivirus batch file

Tags: batch-file, antivirus

Here is my current file.
    :loop
    netstat -a -b -n >> log.txt
    timout 300 /nobreak >nul
    goto loop

It logs all connections.  When you use the -b switch with the netstat command, it tells you what program it running on.  I need to filter out all of those results that show up as "system".  here's what I mean.

here is a line from the netstat -a -b -n command

```
  FDResPub
 [System]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*
```

see where it says [system]?  I want everything that has system in it, to not be displayed, so only non-windows apps get logged.

**edit:**

I know to use the `find -v` command, and that does "what I want", but it still gives me all the extra junk.  I really just need a way to prevent that.

Comment: Well, I can use the `netstat -a -b -n | find /v "[system]"`, but I still get a bunch of extra junk.

Comment: in addition, with the `find /v` it only doesn't display the line with [system].  The surrounding lines that are described by system still get displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
:loop
netstat -a -b -n | findstr /iv "system" >> log.txt
timout 300 /nobreak >nul
goto loop
```

What's going on here is that we're piping all the output to the findstr command and using it to filter out anything that's has the word "system" in it. If you need it to be more specific, you can add in the brackets from your example. `netstat -a -b -n | findstr /iv /c:"[system]" >> log.txt`